# Android Studio - Github url for push not working/changing

Tags: android, git, github

I am trying to push to github.iu.edu. I went to Setting --> Version Control --> GitHub and changed the host, login, and password to be correct and it passes the test.

However, when I go to VCS --> Git --> Push (after adding, and commiting), it asks for push to github.com and tries to push to my other account at this URL.

How do I get my project to push to the github.iu.edu. I can do it just fine in the Git Shell, just not Android Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the GitHub integration on Android Studio doesn't work well with setting two different accounts or doesn't work well with GitHub enterprise.
You should try to define the repository through the git directory instead of the built-in GitHub integration of Android Studio.

Open *Git Bash* or *terminal*, then navigate to the root of your project.
Then, in order to add the git specifications write `git remote add <remote_name> <remote_url>`.

I think that after that you will be able to push your changes using the native Android Studio GUI (`Right Click => Git => Commit Directory...`) to your remote and everything should work.

Comment: If Android Studio can't handle this, it is no problem. I can always use the Git Shell. Just thought it would be easier to use Git inside Android Studio. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are still able to configure it and use Git inside Android Studio, just not through the GitHub integration. As one is able to access git using BitBucket and GitLab etc. without a built-in integration for those sites, so do you in your case. Maybe try to delete git setup from the root of your project and then create a new link to your remote repository, just to make sure you're overwriting the previous settings. After that, you will be able to use git from Android Studio itself again.

Comment: I do not know how to do this. Are you able to explain, please. I thought I did it, but still ran into the original problem. :/

Comment: Your goal here is to delete  the git-related information (branches, versions, etc.) and the easiest way to do that is to delete the `.git` directory in the root directory of your repository. Bare in mind that this action will remove the documentation of uncommitted changes (the code will stay the same).

Comment: sorry for the delay. got it figured out with your help! thanks for helping ;)